# How to implement the SimplePie force_feed function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

When I try to parse a specific RSS feed using the native RSS widget for WordPress I receive the following error:

> RSS Error: A feed could not be found at 
>   http://trustbox.trustpilot.com/r/harringtonbrooks.co.uk.xml.  A feed
>   with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error,  or SimplePie
>   was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed()  if you are certain
>   this URL is a real feed.

I have validated the feed using the http://validator.w3.org/feed/ and it states that the feed is valid. I belive that the mime type is also correct for the feed - `type="application/rss+xml"`

After consulting the SimplePie documentation this code is suggested as the fix - however I am clueless as to where this code would actually be implemeted within the WordPress installation.

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('MY FEED URL');
$feed->force_feed(true);
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();
echo $feed->get_title();
```

Alternatively are there any other suggestions for getting this RSS feed to actually be parsed by the reader?